# How to track which users click link/button?

Tags: links

I'd like to be able to track specifically which users click a link or button in a private paid members only section of my site. For example, if the user lands on the link site.com/media/1.pdf, I would like to know which users land on that link.

This is to ensure that users do not download all of my content and then run away.

Thanks!

Comment: How is your PDF being served? Is it a static file on disk, i.e. will be served by the web server directly independently of WordPress, or is it through some permissions check at the point of download that you could hook to record which user? There are also ways to report link clicks at the point of click - e.g. on click fires off an AJAX request, and I think there might be a mechanism built into HTML even - but I'd probably try to track the file as it's downloaded. Although that gets slightly complicated if all your PDFs are hosted on CDNs, not on the site directly.

Comment: If you're worried about your members downloading all your content in one go then you might need to throttle how much they can download in a day, say.

Comment: It's served from the standard wordpress uploads folder, which I assume is static? There are no permissions check to my knowledge, however that is something I am open to if possible - i.e, the user must have purchased 'product a' in order to open the link. Maybe that's way ahead of myself... one thing at a time ha. Your latter idea is also a good idea, though I would prefer the use of tracking if possible?